# SQL BULK INSERT with on the fly table creation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, bulkinsert

I would like to use BULK INSERT to load a few hundred raw data tables into SQL Server. The format of these tables would be similar, although not identical (they come from excel sheets which are not tightly version controlled).

I want to know if there is a way to dynamically generate the table required on SQL Server depending on the headers in the file to be loaded, and then do the BULK INSERT thereafter.

Comment: Does this need to be done in TSQL, or are you willing/able to write some .NET code?

Comment: Preferably in TSQL, but if it has to then I set up a small .net app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to those Excel tables using OPEN ROWSET. Then, do the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM Excel
INTO NewTable
WHERE 0=1
```

This will transfer the schema. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yeah this works. Did it like this (after an intermediate step of converting the xls files to csv - which wasn't really necessary): SELECT * into NewTable FROM OPENROWSET 
('MSDASQL', 'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};DBQ=C:\FolderName\;', 'SELECT * from [filename.csv]');

Comment: Be aware that the default types SQL derives from the spreadsheet are terrible. This table is in a bad state.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an excel script that generates sql statements for creation of the tables, then execute the file before bulk insert the data.